# can not connect to server socket to transfer data in android

Tags: android, sockets

I am trying to build an Android app where two phones will be able to send text messages to each other without a data or cellular connection, but instead using a WiFi connection. I found out [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) that I need to make a p2p (wifidirect) connection first and then try to use a server socket to wait for a client to connect and send data. Now, I can establish the p2p connection, but I can't use a socket to transfer the data. I am getting a null result in my `onPostExecute()` method on both the client and server side. How should I establish the server and client?

I made an object of each class in my MainActivity to start the client and server side. They both are executed in background method.

```
 Client task = new Client(MainActivity.this,d.deviceAddress );
 task.execute();

sever task = new server(MainActivity.this);
              task.execute();
```

Here is my server side:

```
public class server extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    InputStream inputstream ;
    Socket client;
    ByteArrayOutputStream result;
    byte[] buffer;
    private Context context;
    public static InetAddress address;
    public static  boolean connected; 

    public server(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket;

        //byte[] ipAddress={'5','4','3','1'};

         try {

                address = InetAddress.getByName("hazel");// i tried to use getByAddress(ipAddress) as well ,no change 
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888,10,address);
               // serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
                client = serverSocket.accept();
                connected =true;


            } catch (IOException e) { 
                return null;
            }
        return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

           if (result != null) {
                 super.onPostExecute(result);
                 Toast.makeText(context, "result is  "+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 } 
                 Toast.makeText(context, " is someone connected  "+ connected  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}
```

Here is the client side:

```
public class Client extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Context ctx;
    String deviceAddress ;
    String sek;
    boolean isresolved =  false;
    InetAddress inetaddress;


      Client task = new Client(MainActivity.this,d.deviceAddress );
      task.execute();
    public Client(MainActivity ctx, String deviceAddress) {

        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.deviceAddress = deviceAddress;

    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)  {

                String host="hazel";
                int port=8888;

                int len;
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                byte buf[]  = new byte[1024];

                try {

                      socket.bind(null);

                  //  byte[] ipAddress={'5','4','3','1'};

                    inetaddress = InetAddress.getByName("hazel");
                    InetSocketAddress address =  new InetSocketAddress(inetaddress,8888);


                    isresolved = address.isUnresolved();
                    // the isresolved will get false value after executing the code 
                    // i think it means that adress has no problem 


                    socket.connect(address,1000); 



                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Log.v("Exception" , "is " + e);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v("Exception" , "is " + e);

                }

                finally {
                    if (socket != null) {
                        if (socket.isConnected()) {
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {

                                Log.v("Exception " , "is " + e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }       

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null) {            
            super.onPostExecute(result);
             Toast.makeText(ctx, "clientside , result :  "+result  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }else  Toast.makeText(ctx, "result is null :(" , result :  "+result  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

When I run the server side the `onPostExecute` will be called with the null result. I am expecting the `onPostExecute to be called after someone in connected to the server.

On the client side I am getting a null result on `onPostExecute` method and also is unresolved method returns false.

I need to connect to the server first to send data so can anyone point out what is wrong with my logic? I tried to create the socket in different ways (such as port, port with hostname, port with ip address)  and put `serverSocket.accept()`, but it did not work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well its so sad that i have to answer my question but in p2p connection the ip is always constant. its "192.168.49.1". so i just created a socket like below

clientSocket= new Socket("192.168.49.1",9889);

its no matter if you run your code in doInBackgroundmethod or a new thread but the ports must be the same

Answer (score 0):

1. `doInBackground` never returns anything but `null`, so `onPostExecute` doesn't see anything else
2. If you want the Server to continuously run and listen for connections, you need a Thread / Service to infinitely run and accept connections. An `AsyncTask` is meant to run short-lived tasks.
3. You might want to look into more reactive-programming with callbacks for an `onClientConnect()` method, for example.